# perform operations based on data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, performancecounter, query-performance

I am performing an operation where I need to operate based on some requirements and the query is::

```
MATCH (n:Label1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:REL_1]-(e:Label2)
WITH n,e,
CASE
    WHEN e IS NULL THEN 
      MERGE (ss:Label2{sId:n.id}) 
      ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
      ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
      CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
  WHEN e.id<1476988200 THEN 
    MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: n.id})
    ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
    ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
    CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
  WHEN e.id=1476988200 AND e.setC < 3 THEN
    MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: n.id})
    ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
    ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
    CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
END
```

Although I have added same cases here; there are different scenarios for every case.

(As I am not able to explain probelm I wrote this:: sorry for that)

But I am getting an error like ::

```
Invalid input ')': expected whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 6, column 36 (offset: 138))
```

To achive this :: I tried like this (But still error produced) ::

```
MATCH (n:Label1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:REL_1]-(e:Label2)
WITH n,e
WHERE e IS NULL OR e.id<1476988200 OR (e.id=1476988200 AND e.setC < 3)
 WITH collect(n) as total_rows
  FOREACH (i IN RANGE(0, size(total_rows)-1) |
  FOREACH (sub IN [total_rows[i]] |
  MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: sub.id})
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1 AND ss.nl = [6]
  ON MATCH SET CASE WHEN ss.id = 1476988200 THEN (ss.setC = ss.setC +1 AND ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]) WHEN ss.id< 1476988200 THEN (ss.id = 1476988200 AND ss.setC = 0 AND ss.nl = []) END
  CREATE UNIQUE (sub)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
  )
  )
```

Error :: `Invalid input 'C': expected whitespace, comment or '.' (line 11, column 3 (offset: 553))`

What is the problem ? Or Is there any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `CASE` only selects an expression to evaluate in place of another expression; no `MATCH`, `CREATE`, etc are allowed inside. What you'll want to do for a query like this is basically make a list of rows, filter that list into three separate lists for rows of a particular kind, then `UNWIND` and process each list separately. UPDATE: The workaround for potential empty lists is complex, so it'll be easiest to just use three separate queries and `UNION ALL`.

```
MATCH (n:Label1)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:REL_1]-(:Label2)
MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: n.id}) 
  ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
  CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
RETURN 'null_rows' AS type, COUNT(*) AS num
UNION ALL
MATCH (n:Label1)-[:REL_1]-(e:Label2)
WHERE e.id < 1476988200
MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: n.id})
  ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
  CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
RETURN 'less_than_rows' AS type, COUNT(*) AS num
UNION ALL
MATCH (n:Label1)-[:REL_1]-(e:Label2)
WHERE e.id = 1476988200 AND e.setC < 3
MERGE (ss:Label2 {sId: n.id})
  ON MATCH SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = ss.setC +1,ss.nl = ss.nl + [4]
  ON CREATE SET ss.id = 1476988200, ss.setC = 1,ss.nl = [6]
  CREATE UNIQUE (n)-[:REL_1]->(ss)
RETURN 'other_rows' AS type, COUNT(*) AS num
```

Comment: Thanks, but if "null_rows and less_than_rows" rows doesn't contain any data and "other_rows" is not updating anything. Means If I remove all of above conditions (null_rows and less_than_rows) then (other_rows) updating. What went wrong.. (sry for delay)

Comment: `UNWIND`ing an empty row will delete the original row from your query (there are no values to create for your new alias). You can work around it, but for this case, it'll be much easier to just use `UNION` to run three separate queries, basically. Make sure you have an index on `:Label2(id)` **and** `:Label2(setC)` to get the best performance out of this.